# Как получить скриншоты середины каждой сцены с помощью FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Этот код делает скриншоты первого кадра каждой новой сцены:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vsync 0 -vf select='gt(scene\,0.4)' -f image2 img-%04d.png
```

Как получить скриншоты середины каждой сцены?

Например: начало сцены - 1:25; конец сцены - 1:31. Как получить скриншот на 1:28?

Я пробовал так:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vsync 0 -vf select='(prev_selected_t*gt(scene\,0.4)+t*gt(scene\,0.4))/2' -f image2 img-%04d.png
```

Такой способ не работает. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Фильтрация работает в конвейере, а значит может процессить только текущий фрейм. Длинна сцены, параметр, в общем случае, неизвестный, соответственно, что бы вычислить середину сцены, нужно сначала узнать её конец, но когда вы будете в конце оной, кадр из прошлого (середины) уже будет недоступен: и механизма сохранения кадров нет (в отличии от выражений, где вы можете использовать st/ld (http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation))